# Print string multiple times

Tags: shell-script

I want to write a script which takes two parameters, a string and a number. The script with print the string n time rounded with asterisks. So for ex. `script "Hello World!" 3` will print:

```
**************
*Hello World!*
*Hello World!*
*Hello World!*
**************
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `printf '*HelloWorld*\n%.0s' {1..3}`

Comment: but i can not print the first and last line with asterisks. Also I want to do it with parameters not manually.

Comment: I take it that you need to do this with a single `printf` statement?  As you could simply just perform a `printf '************\n` before and after your existing `printf`, right?

Comment: I cant to that because length will vary on the string length. and it need to be a script which takes parameters.

Comment: `echo $1 | sed 's/./*/g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make a string of `*` characters the same length as the input with `sed`.  We can also loop pretty simply.  The output of each line would then be

```
*$stars*
*$input*
...repeated...
*$stars*
```

So we can make a simple "output" function that just puts the `*` around the required string

```
#!/bin/bash

string=$1
count=$2

stars=$(echo "$string" | sed 's/./*/g')

output() { printf "*%s*\n" "$1"; }

output "$stars"
for ((a=0;a<$count;a++))
{
  output "$string"
}
output "$stars"
```

eg

```
./x "Hello world!" 3
**************
*Hello world!*
*Hello world!*
*Hello world!*
**************
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is using seq for the number of times the string is echo'd, and printf with string manipulation for the asterisks.

```
SAY=$1
NUM=$2
CMD="echo *$SAY*"

c="${SAY//[*]}**"
s=$(printf "%-${#c}s" "*")
echo "${s// /*}"

for i in $(seq $NUM)
do $CMD
done

echo "${s// /*}"
```

You can then use this script with arguments `./script.sh "Hello World" 3`

Comment: And the asterisks?

Comment: Oops, completely missed that! I've edited my answer accordingly.